# How to restrict certain words in text field using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contact form in my website. Subject is a text field in this form. I want to restrict users to type certain words in that field.

For example a user type XXX  or MMM in subject field, we need to show error message.

Comment: You would want to replace text or do some sort of alert while reading what is being input on your subject line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

HTML:

```
<input id='text'></input>
```

You can do this:

JS:

```
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    if (text.search('MMM') !== -1) {
        alert('MMM is not allowed!');
    }
    if (text.search('XXX') !== -1) {
        alert('XXX is not allowed!');
    }
    text = text.replace(/MMM/g,'');
    text = text.replace(/XXX/g,'');
    document.getElementById('text').value = text;
},false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ka7ds5yo/)

OR this:

JS:

```
var banned = ['MMM','XXX'];
document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    for (var x=0;x<banned.length;x++) {
        if (text.search(banned[x]) !== -1) {
            alert(banned[x]+' is not allowed!');
        }
        var regExp = new RegExp(banned[x]);
        text = text.replace(regExp,'');
    }
    document.getElementById('text').value = text;
},false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ka7ds5yo/1/)

However, you also need to sanitize these form responses on your server. Any client code can be circumvented.